# Is there a way to check the independence of observations within a Poisson distribution?

Tags: distributions, independence, poisson-distribution

I have the understanding that one of the key assumptions of a Poisson distribution is that the observations are **independent**.

Is there a way of testing the independence of the observations within a Poisson distribution, or is the assumption of independence set at the design stage of the research.

Comment: That is not an assumption of the Poisson distribution. Are you talking about the assumption of independence of events in a *Poisson process* or are you talking about an assumption of independence in some model involving the Poisson distribution? When you mention research, what sort of research are you doing?

Comment: Sorry I've conflated the Poisson distribution and the Poisson process; yes, the assumption of independence of events. In this case, I'm analysing a study which involves count data, and have noticed the authors have not assessed the suitability of the Poisson regression model, or made mention of the fulfilment of the key assumptions, other than by a maximum likelihood estimation method.

Comment: 1. the Poisson process assumption would be about the events making up each count (i.e. you don't have access to when the events occurred so how do you assess that for each count?). 2. The Poisson variates in some model don't necessarily have to be independent of each other, it depends on the model (sometimes yes, sometimes no, you'd assume independence for a Poisson regression). 3. You don't necessarily need to demonstrate that you have a Poisson process for a Poisson distribution to be a suitable approximation in the context of some model....

Comment: ...  4. You could try to identify non-independence of Poisson counts within a Poisson regression model if you had some idea of the likely kinds of dependence. That would depend on the particular circumstances. (you might look for spatial dependence in observations in space for example, like if you had counts of some particular kind of plant in some set of squares in a forest or you might look for time dependence for data over time etc etc)

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica!